# itk OtsuMultipleThresholdsImageFilter does not process

Tags: c++, opencv, itk

I am trying to use ITK's OtsuMultipleThresholdsImageFilter filter in a project but I do not have output.

My aim is to make a simple interface between OpenCV and ITK.
To convert my data from OpenCV's Mat container to itk::Image I use ITK's bridge to OpenCV and I could check that the data are properly sent to ITK.
I am even able to display thanks to QuickView.

But When I setup the filter inspired by [this](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/Thresholding/ThresholdAnImageUsingOtsu/Documentation.html) example the object returned by the method `GetThresholds()` is empty.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
   typedef itk::Image<uchar,2> image_type;
    typedef itk::OtsuMultipleThresholdsImageFilter<image_type, image_type> filter_type;

    image_type::Pointer img = itk::OpenCVImageBridge::CVMatToITKImage<image_type>(src);

    image_type::SizeType size = img->GetLargestPossibleRegion().GetSize();

    filter_type::Pointer filter = filter_type::New();


    filter->SetInput(img);

    filter->SetNumberOfHistogramBins(256);
    filter->SetNumberOfThresholds(K);

    filter_type::ThresholdVectorType tmp = filter->GetThresholds();

    std::cout<<"CHECK: "<<tmp.size()<<std::endl;
```

`src` is OpenCV's Mat of CV_8U(C1) type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fundamental and basic concept to using ITK is that it is a pipeline architecture. You must connect the input's and output's then update the pipeline.

You have connected the pipeline but you have not executed it. You must call `filter->Update()`.

Please read the ITK Software Guide to understand the fundamentals of ITK:
https://itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much this fix everything :)
Thank you also for the reference :)